# Optimal Policy under Commitment

Tags: macroeconomics, new-keynesian-economics, lagrangian

Hi I'm trying to wrap my head around an equation in Jordi Galís book "Monetary Policy, Inflation and the Business Cycle"

Under commitment the Central Bank has the following optimization problem:
$$\min_{x_t,\pi_t}E_0\left\{\sum^\infty_{t=0}\beta^t(\pi_t^2-\vartheta x_t^2)\right\}$$
Subject to the constraints:
$$\pi_t=\beta E_t\{\pi_{t+1}\}+\kappa x_t+u_t$$

From this he constructs the Lagrangian:
$$\mathcal{L}=E_0\left\{\sum^\infty_{t=0}\beta^t\left[(\pi_t^2-\vartheta x_t^2)+\xi_t(\pi_t-\kappa x_t-\beta\pi_{t+1})\right]\right\}$$

The thing I don't understand is why the constraint is inside the expectation. Normally while optimizing by lagrange multipliers I would have written the problem like this:
$$\mathcal{L}=\sum^\infty_{t=0}E_0\left\{\beta^t(\pi_t^2-\vartheta x_t^2)\right\}+\xi_t(\pi_t-\kappa x_t-\beta E_t\{\pi_{t+1}\}-u_t)$$

Does anyone know why it makes sense/works to construct the lagrangian with the constraint inside the expectation?